# JQuery Tooltip Troubleshooting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First off, I'm new to JQuery, so sorry if this is something simple and I'm just missing it.

I'm attempting to use the jquery plugin called "tooltipsy" (http://tooltipsy.com/).

The end goal is for this look here: http://screencast.com/t/4AghhAI7dL

This is what currently happens: screencast[dot]com/t/mBAIm67lM6W1 (sorry, couldn't post more than two links)

Inside my code I've copied it nearly identically from the examples, but I can't seem to get it to work. This is running inside a twig template file for a WordPress website, but I don't believe that, that should affect it (of course I could be, and probably am wrong)?

```
<a class="hastip" title="Phone Here">(ES?)</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src=" {{ wp.get_stylesheet_directory_uri()  }}/assets/js/tooltipsy.min.js">
$('.hastip').tooltipsy();
</script>
```

It links to the CSS file in the header information, and the link works just fine.

My issue is the "tooltip" itself does not appear and I can't figure out why?

Would appreciate any and all help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<a class="hastip" title="Phone Here">(ES?)</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src=" {{ wp.get_stylesheet_directory_uri()  }}/assets/js/tooltipsy.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.hastip').tooltipsy();
});
</script>
```

You can't have code inside a script src.

Comment: I assumed that, so I moved the script source to the header. Was that not the correct location?

Because even once it's been moved, it still does not work.

Comment: Are you loading the jQuery library before the plugin?

Comment: Yes, it loads in the header information before anything else.

Comment: Do you have any link with the actual code? Is the tooltipsy library loading correctly?

Comment: I finally got it to work, now it's just a matter of getting the CSS to load right which I'm pretty good with.

Seems the issue was with the jQuery not loading locally, so by adding it to the local file it connected it correctly. Has something to do with the fact that twig loads the file before sending it to WordPress.

Comment: Post the solution for next visitors. I'm glad you could solve it.